# Gray our disabled kendo ui grid column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/UfOfi) a kendo ui grid
the first column [OrderID] is not editable.
I'm looking to make all disabled columns **grayed out**, so the user knows that this is not editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1) Apply a particular class for that column in kendo grid using

```
columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grayCol"}).Width("5%");
```

2) And apply whatever style you need for that class

```
.grayCol{background-color:#ffffff;};
```

Comment: Thanks! i would like a way that i dont need a class on each cell if possible just on the header. But if not your code would do it